# AsyncMqttclient publish affects accelerometer readings

Tags: esp32, accelerometer, mqtt

Using M5StickC ESP32 with built-in MPU6886 accelerometer to read vibrations. In the loop() section the code gets 10 readings per second and if the readings exceed a threshold, it starts publishing the results in a JSON MQTT message on asyncmqttclient, again 10 publishes per second. The period of full publishing continues on until the readings fall back under the threshold+5 seconds.

However,when it starts publishing 10 messages per second, the accelerometer readings go haywire and the values are higher than they should be in reality. This is the results under asyncmqttclient publish:

[image]

The blue ellipse is just one knock. Goes up and down, and the vibration ends there. However the green ellipse part is the period where the code sends the publish messages, they should normally be down and silent like this:

[image]

This second graph values are from the same code, the only difference is i commented out the asyncmqttclient publish mqtt command. If i use pubsubclient it also gives the correct values.

```
if (eq_status) { // Earthquake still happening
  eq_time_count++ ;

  if (((slta && !staLta.checkTrigger()) || (!slta && eq_time_count > eq_pet)) || (master && !slave_eq_state)) { // EQ Ends...              
      eq_status = false;
      eq_time_count = 0;

      updateState("LISTENING");

      publish_mqtt(MQTT_PUB_EVENT, updateEvent(ax,ay,az,pga).c_str(), 0, true);

      digitalWrite(M5_LED, HIGH);
      if (SPK_HAT) ledcWriteTone(spkChannel, 0);
      lcd.set_brightness(lcd_brightness);
  } else {
    /* THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC PART */
    publish_mqtt(MQTT_PUB_EVENT, updateEvent(ax,ay,az,pga).c_str(), 0, true);
    /*client.publish(MQTT_PUB_EVENT,updateEvent(ax,ay,az,pga).c_str());*/

  }
} else {
    if (flush_update) { // Send periodic event update message
    flush_event++;
    if (flush_event > (flush_period*10)) {
      publish_mqtt(MQTT_PUB_EVENT, updateEvent(ax,ay,az,pga).c_str(), 0, true);
      flush_event = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I think there could be something wrong with either asyncmqttclient or espasyncTCP, or could there be any other cause?

Comment: Decreasing 10 publishes per second to 5 publishes helps a lot. Is it a problem of message buffer?

Comment: I could be missing something. But this might be viewed as too general a question. Perhaps if you broke it down more and tested those smaller aspects of the project before coming here we could better help.  In the mean time, the [MPU-6886](https://m5stack.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/resource/docs/datasheet/core/MPU-6886-000193%2Bv1.1_GHIC_en.pdf) can be I2C or SPI.  Have you tried both?  And the [async-mqtt-client](https://github.com/marvinroger/async-mqtt-client) has its own web page.  Have you looked there for answers ... through the open issues?

Comment: "Is it a problem of message buffer?"  Maybe.  I am not familiar with ESP32 I2C HW.  Or, if you are using a SW implemented I2C (or SPI, you didn't say which mode you set the MPU-6886 to) to talk to the MPU-6886 it may be adversely affected by the async-mqtt-client SW.  This is an embedded environment, not a real OS.  If async-mqtt-client is using a lot of the CPUs time, this may impact the expected operation of your code or features (like I2C) your code is depending on.

Comment: I am using I2C, couldn't find the SPI library of it. asyncmqttclient has no information in this kind of problem. I heavily suspect that the problem may be about the TCP buffer since decreasing the publishes per second helped. But I still don't have any clue how it can affect the accelerometer read values.